# Hiding a tr with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Why doesn't this work? :

```
<table id="table1">
   <tr id="trSS">
      detail1
   </tr>
   <tr id="trEstate">
      detail2
   </tr>   
</table>
```

With :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trSS").hide();
}​);
```

Not working, as in detail1 and detail2 are always displayed, where detail1 should be hidden by the code.

Comment: the html is not correct: <td> tags missing

Comment: Nevertheless you should not edit it in the question. The question is then not clear anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the table cell elements:

```
<table id="table1">
   <tr id="trSS">
      <td>detail1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="trEstate">
      <td>detail2</td>
   </tr>   
</table>
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNDpW/)

Comment: Yeah.. I've noticed that the `td` elements were missing, I ended up creating the same thing on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CQCTL/

Answer (score 1):

The table is not valid, you should have a td inside the tr:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr id="trSS">
       <td>detail1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trEstate">
       <td>detail2</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no columns in your rows.

Answer (score 0):

The browser you are using probably does not correctly support the invalid HTML on your page (you have rows with text but no TDs)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="table1"> 
   <tr id="trSS"> 
       <div id="trSSContent">detail1</div>
   </tr> 
   <tr id="trEstate"> 
      detail2 
   </tr>    
</table>
```

​​​​

You can use the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#trSSContent").hide(); 
}); ​
```

And please not that your  is not a html-correct code